# Ionic Zip: Extract zip file with folder addition

Tags: c#

I, or better, we have a big problem!
Our favorite game, Trove, has changed it's structure to be more moddable. Now we sit on our ModLoader and don't know how to update it. It should keep the old structure but it needs to apply a folder to each existing folder in the zips root. Let me show you:

```
mod.zip
|-blueprints
| |-fileA
|
|-particles
| |-fileB
```

It has to be extracted to each Live/blueprints/override/... and Live/particles/override/... (this is just an example... in a real mod, there are more folders and more files)

How can I do that? Is it possible with Ionic? Or do I have to use an other library?

Comment: You want  to extract a zip and keep directory structure?

Comment: Well, kinda... the contents of the folders in the zip should be extracted to a folder within the actual folder. So in my example, mod.zip/blueprints/fileA has to be extracted to Live/blueprints/override/fileA and mod.zip/particles/fileB has to be extracted to Live/particles/override/fileB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, something like this should work if I understood what you need.

```
private const string ZIP_FILE = @"c:\temp\mod.zip";

static void Main()
{
    // delete if already there
    File.Delete(ZIP_FILE);

    // create example zip file
    using(ZipFile zipToPack = new ZipFile(ZIP_FILE))
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\fileA.txt", "This is file A");
        zipToPack.AddFile(@"c:\temp\fileA.txt", "blueprints");
        File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\fileB.txt", "This is file B");
        zipToPack.AddFile(@"c:\temp\fileB.txt", "particles");
        zipToPack.Save();
    }

    // extract inserting extra directory
    string baseExtractDir = @"c:\temp\LIVE";
    string overrideDir = "override";

    using (ZipFile zipToUnpack = new ZipFile(ZIP_FILE))
    {
        // loop through each entry in the zip file
        foreach (var zipEntry in zipToUnpack)
        {                    
            if (zipEntry.IsDirectory) continue;
            string zipDirectoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(zipEntry.FileName);
            // create the target file path as follows:
            // ("c:\temp\LIVE") + zip file path ("blueprints") + our extra path ("override") + zip file name ("fileA.txt")
            string targetExtractFile = Path.Combine(baseExtractDir, zipDirectoryPath, overrideDir, Path.GetFileName(zipEntry.FileName));
            // create the directory path if needed
            string targetExtractDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(targetExtractFile);
            if (!Directory.Exists(targetExtractDir)) Directory.CreateDirectory(targetExtractDir);
            // extract the zip file to our target file name
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(targetExtractFile, FileMode.Create))
                zipEntry.Extract(stream);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Do you think this will also work when there are subfolders?
Example:
particles/VFX/FileA,
particles/animation/FileB,
blueprint/FileC 
and so on

Comment: Yes, though in this case it will extract to `particles\VFX\override\fileA`. If you wanted your extra path higher up the chain it can be done differently though.

Comment: Okay, it doesn't work... it just creates a file called override (but it's in the right directory)
EDIT: Here's what it looks like http://pastebin.com/pK0Z6e6S (ignore the message box... just debugging)

Comment: The code above certainly doesn't do that. Debug, check what the zip entry paths/files names are. Unless you provide the zip I can't do it for you.

Comment: targetExtractFile is C:\Program Files(x86)\Glyph\Games\Trove\Live\blueprints\override and a zip file is http://www.trovesaurus.com/mod.php?id=11&download=33 or (with subdirectories) http://www.trovesaurus.com/mod.php?id=17&file=37

Comment: the first entry in the zip is not really a file. see modification above to just skip it, any better?