# How to go from byte[], to MemoryStream, Unzip, then write to FileStream

Tags: c#, filestream, zip, memorystream

I am unsure what I am doing wrong. The files that I create after grabbing a `byte[]` (which is emailAttachment.Body) and passing it to  the method ExtractZipFile, converting it to `MemoryStream` and then unzipping it, returning it as a `KeyValuePair` and then Writing to a file using `FileStream`.

However when I go to open the new created files there is an error in opening them. They are not able to be opened.

The below are in the same class

```
using Ionic.Zip;

var extractedFiles = ExtractZipFile(emailAttachment.Body);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, MemoryStream> extractedFile in extractedFiles)
{                               
    string FileName = extractedFile.Key;
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(CurrentFileSystem + 
    FileName.FileFullPath(),FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[extractedFile.Value.Length];
        extractedFile.Value.Read(bytes, 0, (int) xtractedFile.Value.Length);
        file.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
        extractedFile.Value.Close();
     }
}


private Dictionary<string, MemoryStream> ExtractZipFile(byte[] messagePart)
{
    Dictionary<string, MemoryStream> result = new Dictionary<string,MemoryStream>();
    MemoryStream data = new MemoryStream(messagePart);
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(data))
    {
        foreach (ZipEntry ent in zip)
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            ent.Extract(memoryStream);
            result.Add(ent.FileName,memoryStream);
        }   
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there something I am missing? I do not want to save the original zip file just the extracted Files from `MemoryStream`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [This question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31008315/215552) seems to do what you're looking for. Hard to say since you add the `Dictionary` in there.

Comment: To start with you should be disposing everything that is disposable.

Comment: Also, don't do `CurrentFileSystem + FileName.FileFullPath()`, always do `System.IO.Path.Combine(CurrentFileSystem, FileName.FileFullPath())`.

Comment: And your code has a minor syntax error too. Is this the actual code that you're using?

Comment: Make sure that you set the position of your MemoryStream back to 0 after writing to it, because I doubt `ent.Extract` is going to take care of it

Comment: @Enigmativity I cut the code and slightly edited it to put it into stackoverflow. It compiles and runs correctly.

Comment: @KevinGosse found it. Sidenote: `Stream` has a very convenient `CopyTo` method. Or maybe even more convenient, extract the `ZipEntry` directly to the newly created `FileStream`.

Comment: @DarrenWood - Not with the variable `xtractedFile`. It's minor, but it shows that you didn't test this specific the code before posting.

Comment: @DarrenWood - Can you please show the full error that you're getting and on which line?

Comment: @Enigmativity The error was in opening the files in my Solution Explorer after the files had been saved. It was not in the c# program. The files were not created properly.  It now works. I am sorry if I was not clear about the problem.

Comment: @Enigmativity The error specifically was 'It Appears that we don't support this file format'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing to your MemoryStream, you're not setting the position back to 0:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
ent.Extract(memoryStream);
result.Add(ent.FileName,memoryStream);
```

Because of this, the stream position will be at the end when you try to read from it, and you'll read nothing. Make sure to rewind it:

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

Also, you don't have to handle the copy manually. Just let the `CopyTo` method take care of it:

```
extractedFile.Value.CopyTo(file);
```

Comment: I would not have found this solution myself. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you clean up your use of `MemoryStream` in your code.

I agree that calling `memoryStream.Position = 0;` will allow this code to work correctly, but it's an easy thing to miss when reading and writing memory streams.

It's better to write code that avoids the bug.

Try this:

```
private IEnumerable<(string Path, byte[] Content)> ExtractZipFile(byte[] messagePart)
{
    using (var data = new MemoryStream(messagePart))
    {
        using (var zipFile = ZipFile.Read(data))
        {
            foreach (var zipEntry in zipFile)
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    zipEntry.Extract(memoryStream);
                    yield return (Path: zipEntry.FileName, Content: memoryStream.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then your calling code would look something like this:

```
foreach (var extractedFile in ExtractZipFile(emailAttachment.Body))
{
    File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(CurrentFileSystem, extractedFile.Path.FileFullPath()), extractedFile.Content);
}
```

It's just a lot less code and a much better chance of avoiding bugs. The number one predictor of bugs in code is the number of lines of code you write.

Comment: I appreciate the code. I have implemented it. Unfortunately I am 1 of 2 Developers rapidly working for our company and I don't consider always efficiency with the code, just something that works. I was new to memory streams and looked for a solution on stackoverflow and used that. I might try using the site CodeReview to get some feedback. It was good to get some feedback though. I have learnt something.

Comment: @DarrenWood - It's always worth trying to learn new ways to do things - especially if they help to write less buggy code. The only thing I would caution is that any solution you find online you should scrutinize before putting it in to production code. Don't just blithely copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

Since I find it all a lot of code for a simple operation, here's my two cents.

```
using Ionic.Zip;

using (var s = new MemoryStream(emailAttachment.Body))
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(s))
{
    foreach (ZipEntry ent in zip)
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(CurrentFileSystem, ent.FileName.FileFullPath())
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            ent.Extract(file);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: It was a lot of code and I am happy to have learnt something about efficiency. Thanks for you answer

Comment: or even `zip.ExtractAll(CurrentFileSystem)` might work actually?

Comment: Note that programmatically extracting zip files from email attachments may cause a significant security risk...